# regular expression for wildcard domain validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to writing regular expressions. I am planning to write regular expression for validating wild card domain matching. Here are scenarios.

Correct:

- `*.test.com`
- `test.com`
- `abc.test.com`

Incorrect:

- `*test.com`
- `test.com*`
- `test.*.com`
- `test.abc*.com`

Here is my regular expression for above secnario

```
/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|\*\.[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{0,243}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/
```

It is working as expected. can we improve or write better expression?

Comment: to improve your regex, tell us the rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(\*\.)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+$
```

matches your examples.
[Demo 1](http://regex101.com/r/wG1nZ3/1)

From my point of view i would also treat the third negative example as correct.

```
^(([\w-]+\.)|(\*\.))+[\w-]+$
```

[Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/wG1nZ3/2)

edit: 
you may have to adapt the character classes to contains all allowed characters. I wanted to keep the regex easy to read

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working for all above scenarios. I forget to mention in my question that-1.It should have max length 250.    2. It shouldn't allow underscores(_)   3.It should allow hyphen(-)

Comment: `\d` is already included in `\w`, so `[\w\d]+` is the same that `\w+`

Comment: @M42 ok, then i recalled the things wrong. i adapted it, thanx

Comment: @JavaP added the hyphen